# Trying to build openCV - Linker error

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

Im trying to install openCV on a windows 8 machine. However, I keep on getting linker errors which result in many of the builds to fail. An excerp from the build log:

```
    16>------ Build started: Project: opencv_highgui, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
16>  Building Custom Rule C:/opencv-2.4/modules/highgui/CMakeLists.txt
16>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\opencv3\modules\highgui\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
16>  opencv_highgui_pch.cpp
16>  cap.cpp
16>  cap_images.cpp
16>  loadsave.cpp
16>  utils.cpp
16>  window.cpp
16>  window_w32.cpp
16>  cap_cmu.cpp
16>  cap_dshow.cpp
16>  cap_vfw.cpp
16>  cap_ffmpeg.cpp
16>  grfmt_base.cpp
16>  grfmt_bmp.cpp
16>  grfmt_exr.cpp
16>  grfmt_imageio.cpp
16>  grfmt_jpeg.cpp
16>  grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp
16>  grfmt_png.cpp
16>  grfmt_pxm.cpp
16>  grfmt_sunras.cpp
16>  grfmt_tiff.cpp
16>  Generating Code...
16>  Compiling...
16>  bitstrm.cpp
16>  Generating Code...
16>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_core2412d.lib'
```

Ive attempted to build opencv 3 by pulling the master branch from github and as well attempted to build opencv 2.4, both using once Visual Studios 2012 and Visual Studios 2013. All of these lead to the same results, i.e these .lib files are not getting found. I'm using the newest CMake, although I've tried also using an older CMake version. I'm installing in C:\opencv directory, as was advised in the tutorial. This is not the first time im installing this library, and I've never encountered this problem.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?